# How to restrict user from entering floating point numbers in Chrome extension's options

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to restrict user from entering floating point numbers in my Chrome extension's options.

So I decided to use the following code:

```
<input type="number" id="autorefreshIntervalSecs">
```

and noticed that I'm still able to enter non-decimal values in it.

What is the best way to achieve such behavior then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pattern` like this

```
<input type="number" id="autorefreshIntervalSecs" pattern="[0-9]" title="Only Enter Natural Numbers">
```

it will display the Message in `title` as error when user enters something outside `[0-9]` and **SUBMITS**

EDIT: User will still be able to type them but not submit the form.

Comment: No, it doesn't provide any error and I still able to save the extension's settings with a floating point number in it